# numpy diagonal function is slow

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement the connect 4 game in python as a hobby project, and I have no idea, why the search for matches on the diagonals is so slow.
When analyzing my code with `psstats`, I found that this is the bottleneck.
I want to build a computer enemy which analyzes thousands of future steps in the game, therefore performance is an issue.

Does anyone have an idea, how to improve performance the following code?
I chose numpy to do this, because I thought that would speed things up.
The problem is, that I could not find a way to avoid a for loop.

```py
import numpy as np

# Finds all the diagonal and off-diagonal-sequences in a 7x6 numpy array
def findseq(sm,seq=2,redyellow=1):
    matches=0
    # search in the diagonals
    # diags stores all the diagonals and off diagonals as rows of a matrix
    diags=np.zeros((1,6),dtype=np.int8)
    for k in range(-5,7):   
        t=np.zeros(6,dtype=np.int8)
        a=np.diag(sm,k=k).copy()
        t[:len(a)] += a
        s=np.zeros(6,dtype=np.int8)
        a=np.diag(np.fliplr(sm),k=k).copy()
        s[:len(a)] += a
        diags=np.concatenate(( diags,t[None,:],s[None,:]),axis=0)
    diags=np.delete(diags,0,0)
    # print(diags)
    # now, search for sequences
    Na=np.size(diags,axis=1)
    n=np.arange(Na-seq+1)[:,None]+np.arange(seq)
    seqmat=np.all(diags[:,n]==redyellow,axis=2)
    matches+=seqmat.sum()

    return matches

def randomdebug():
    # sm=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,1,1,0,0]])
    sm=np.random.randint(0,3,size=(6,7))
    return sm

# in my main program, I need to do this thousands of times
matches=[]
for i in range(1000):
    sm=randomdebug()
    matches.append(findseq(sm,seq=3,redyellow=1))
    matches.append(findseq(sm,seq=3,redyellow=2))
    # print(sm)
    # print(findseq(sm,seq=3))
```

Here are the `psstats`

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2000    1.965    0.001    4.887    0.002 Frage zu diag.py:4(findseq)
151002/103002    0.722    0.000    1.979    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
    48000    0.264    0.000    0.264    0.000 {method 'diagonal' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    48072    0.251    0.000    0.251    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    48000    0.209    0.000    0.985    0.000 twodim_base.py:240(diag)
    48000    0.179    0.000    1.334    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:177(diag)
    50000    0.165    0.000    0.165    0.000 {built-in method numpy.zeros}
```

I am new to python, so please imagine a tag "hopeless noob" ;-)

Comment: I guess that's not the `np.diag` that is slow but rather copying the arrays in memory...

Comment: Both of those explicit copies are also rather useless, given that the results are immediately used for addition in the subsequent statements and then never used again. Views would work just fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comment by Andrey, the code is calling a lot of np functions that require additional memory allocations. I believe that is the bottleneck.

I would suggest precomputing indices of all diagonals, since they won't change much in your case (matrix shape remains the same, the sequence may change I guess). Then you can use them to address diagonals fast:

```
import numpy as np


known_diagonals = dict()
def diagonal_indices(h: int, w: int, length: int = 3) -> np.array:
    '''
    Returns array (shape diagonal_count x length) of diagonal indices
    of a flatten array
    '''
    # one of many ways to store precomputed function output
    # cleaner way would probably be to do this outside this function
    diagonal_indices_key = (h, w, length)
    if diagonal_indices_key in known_diagonals:
        return known_diagonals[diagonal_indices_key]
    
    diagonals_count = (h + 1 - length) * (w + 1 - length) * 2

    # default value is meant to ease process with cumsum:
    # adding h + 1 selects an index 1 down and 1 right, h - 1 index 1 down 1 left
    # firts half dedicated to right down diagonals
    diagonals = np.full((diagonals_count, length), w + 1, dtype=np.int32)
    # second half dedicated to left down diagonals
    diagonals[diagonals_count//2::] = w - 1

    # this could have been calculated mathematicaly
    flat_indices = np.arange(w * h).reshape((h, w))
    # print(flat_indices)

    # selects rectangle offseted by l - 1 from right and down edges
    diagonal_starts_rd = flat_indices[:h + 1 - length, :w + 1 - length]
    # selects rectangle offseted by l - 1 from left and down edges
    diagonal_starts_ld = flat_indices[:h + 1 - length, -(w + 1 - length):]
    
    # sets starts
    diagonals[:diagonals_count//2, 0] = diagonal_starts_rd.flatten()
    diagonals[diagonals_count//2::, 0] = diagonal_starts_ld.flatten()

    # sum triplets left to right
    # diagonals contains triplets (or vector of other length) of (start, h+-1, h+-1). cumsum makes diagonal indices
    diagonals = diagonals.cumsum(axis=1)

    # save ouput
    known_diagonals[diagonal_indices_key] = diagonals

    return diagonals

# Finds all the diagonal and off-diagonal-sequences in a 7x6 numpy array
def findseq(sm: np.array, seq: int = 2, redyellow: int = 1) -> int:
    matches = 0
    diagonals = diagonal_indices(*sm.shape, seq)

    seqmat = np.all(sm.flatten()[diagonals] == redyellow, axis=1)
    matches += seqmat.sum()

    return matches

def randomdebug():
    # sm=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,1,1,0,0]])
    sm=np.random.randint(0,3,size=(6,7))
    return sm

# in my main program, I need to do this thousands of times
matches=[]
for i in range(1000):
    sm=randomdebug()
    matches.append(findseq(sm,seq=3,redyellow=1))
    matches.append(findseq(sm,seq=3,redyellow=2))
    # print(sm)
    # print(findseq(sm,seq=3))
```

Comment: Note that calling many Numpy function is indeed the bottleneck but this is not due to the allocation (they take only a small portion of the overall runtime). Numpy has a significant overhead for small arrays: it needs to check the parameters, the arrays shape/type, create iterators, etc. This part is not particularly optimized, mainly because it is a pretty big and complex code hard to optimize.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. Have fun, playing the game: https://connectfour4.azurewebsites.net/